# Sound coming from lower floor to upper floor

Tags: sound-proofing

I am a new homeowner and this is my first post to this group. We were living in leased apartment before this and now moved to a two floor house. The problem is if my husband is working in the kitchen or watching TV etc on the lower floor, I can hear all the sound in the bedroom on upper floor. If I close the door of bedroom its fine. I always thought there would be some sound proofing between different floors. Is it normal to hear sounds like this in house or is there something wrong built/missed in this house?

Comment: If you close the door and it's fine, doesn't that mean all the sound is coming through the door?  So the "between the floors" noise isn't really a problem?  Is the hallway carpeted or hard flooring?

Comment: The hallway is wooden floor. Also, when the door is closed the sound is less .. but not completely gone, that why I said its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Such is the down side of hard floors; they aid in sound transmission. Carpets used to absorb this, but nobody likes carpet any more.

There is no building code requirement for sound proofing between floors. It is often done as a "feature", but not having it is not indicative of something being "wrong" with the construction.

Answer (score 0):

You might try making some acoustical panels and hang 2-3 in your upstair and stairway. Here a good video on how you might accomplish this on-the-cheap.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pABvTWSxOes